# isolating a sub list from a big list in python

Tags: python

I have a big list in python like this small example:

small example:

```
['MLEEDMEVAIKMVVVGNGAVGKSSMIQRYCKGIFTKDYKKTIGVDFLERQIQVNDEDVRLMLWDTAGQEEFDAITKAYYRGAQACVLVFSTTDRESFEAV', 'MDHTEGSPAEEPPAHAPSPGKFGERPPPKRLTREAMRNYLKERGDQTVLILHAKVAQKSYGNEKRFFCPPPCVYLMGSGWKKKKEQMERDGCSEQESQPCAFIGIGNSDQEMQQLNLEGKNYCTAKTLYISDSDKRKHFMLSVKMFYGNSDDIGVFLSKRIKVISKPSKKKQSLKNADLCIASGTKVALFNRLRSQTVSTRYLHVEGGNFHASSQQWGAFFIHLLDDDESEGEEFTVRDGYIHYGQTVKLVCSVTGMALPRLIIRKVDKQTALLDADDPVSQLHKCAFYLKDTERMYLCLSQERIIQFQATPCPKEPNKEMINDGASWTIISTDKAEYTFYEGMGPVLAPVTPVPVVESLQLNGGGDVAMLELTGQNFTPNLRVWFGDVEAETMYRCGESMLCVVPDISAFREGWRWVRQPVQVPVTLVRNDGIIYSTSLTFTYTPEPGPRPHCSAAGAILRANSSQVPPNESNTNSEGSYTNASTNSTSVTSSTATVVS']
```

in the file there are many items and each item is a sequence of `characters`. I want to make a new list in which every item has only `one` `W`. the expected output for the small example would be like the expected output.

expected output:

```
['MLEEDMEVAIKMVVVGNGAVGKSSMIQRYCKGIFTKDYKKTIGVDFLERQIQVNDEDVRLMLWDTAGQEEFDAITKAYYRGAQACVLVFSTTDRESFEAV']
```

I am trying to do that in python and wrote the following code:

```
newlist = []
for item in mylist:
    for c in item:
        if c == W:
            newlist.append(item)
```

but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: What is the output you get?
Also, the code you wrote adds all the versions of `item` that contain `W` at all, not once.

Comment: You want proteins with a single Tryptophan? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.count`

**Ex:**

```
res = []
mylist = ['MLEEDMEVAIKMVVVGNGAVGKSSMIQRYCKGIFTKDYKKTIGVDFLERQIQVNDEDVRLMLWDTAGQEEFDAITKAYYRGAQACVLVFSTTDRESFEAV', 'MDHTEGSPAEEPPAHAPSPGKFGERPPPKRLTREAMRNYLKERGDQTVLILHAKVAQKSYGNEKRFFCPPPCVYLMGSGWKKKKEQMERDGCSEQESQPCAFIGIGNSDQEMQQLNLEGKNYCTAKTLYISDSDKRKHFMLSVKMFYGNSDDIGVFLSKRIKVISKPSKKKQSLKNADLCIASGTKVALFNRLRSQTVSTRYLHVEGGNFHASSQQWGAFFIHLLDDDESEGEEFTVRDGYIHYGQTVKLVCSVTGMALPRLIIRKVDKQTALLDADDPVSQLHKCAFYLKDTERMYLCLSQERIIQFQATPCPKEPNKEMINDGASWTIISTDKAEYTFYEGMGPVLAPVTPVPVVESLQLNGGGDVAMLELTGQNFTPNLRVWFGDVEAETMYRCGESMLCVVPDISAFREGWRWVRQPVQVPVTLVRNDGIIYSTSLTFTYTPEPGPRPHCSAAGAILRANSSQVPPNESNTNSEGSYTNASTNSTSVTSSTATVVS']
for item in mylist:
    if item.count("W") == 1:
        res.append(item)
print(res)
```

---

*or*

```
res = [item for item in mylist if item.count("W") == 1]
```

**Output:**

```
['MLEEDMEVAIKMVVVGNGAVGKSSMIQRYCKGIFTKDYKKTIGVDFLERQIQVNDEDVRLMLWDTAGQEEFDAITKAYYRGAQACVLVFSTTDRESFEAV']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are iterating *each character in each string* and appending when a condition is met. Moreover, your logic can't "undo" a `list.append` operation if *another* `W` is found. So if `W` is met twice in a string, you are appending twice.

Instead, you can use a list comprehension with `list.count`:

```
res = [i for i in L if i.count('W') == 1]
```